# HTML Underline and align contents of td

Tags: html, css

I want the content of single td to be underlined. Also the content needs to be two way aligned.
One field to the left and other to the right. How can I achieve this?

### Amount  :                                           10.00 USD

---

Comment: The technology you want to look into is CSS. `border-bottom: 1px #CCCCCC solid` on the right cell(s) will do the job.

Comment: Look at this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/tZHh6/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by specifically setting a width on the 'td' tag then encapsulate the right content on span or em tag.

For the HTML:

```
<td>Amount: <span>10.00 USD</span></td>
```

For the CSS

```
td{
    display:block;
    width:400px;
}

span{
    float:right;
    width:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put an id on your td and split the text in two spans. The second will have to have a "float:right" property and a specific class.

The code might look like this :

CSS :

```
#myTd {
    text-decoration: underlined;
}
#myTd>span.right {
    float: right;
}
```

HTML :

```
...
<td id="myId">
    <span>Amount :</span>
    <span class="right">10.00 USD</span>
</td>
...
```